# How can I modify a fontinst encoding (e.g. t1.etx)?

Tags: font-encodings, fontinst

I am modifying the adobecaslon package to support the Adobe Caslon Expert fonts, basing my work on an old package by Ulrik Vieth for which only some sources are available; I'm also trying to make the package more modular, building on fontinst 1.9.

Adobe Caslon's Expert fonts include st and ct ligatures. To use these, Vieth produced a modified t1.etx encoding file. I would prefer merely to use it an override it. I tried thusly:

```
\relax

\encoding

%% First load the base encoding
\inputetx{t1}

%% Then override some slots
\nextslot{99}
\setslot{\lc{C}{c}}
 \ligature{LIG}{\lc{T}{t}}{ct}
   \comment{The letter `{c}'.}
\endsetslot

\nextslot{115}
\setslot{\lc{S}{s}}
 \ligature{LIG}{\lc{T}{t}}{st}
   \comment{The letter `{s}'.}
\endsetslot

\nextslot{141}
\setslot{ct}
 \comment{The `old style' ligature ct}
\endsetslot

\nextslot{173}
\setslot{st}
 \comment{The `old style' ligature st}
\endsetslot

\endencoding
```

This seems to work nicely, but I get warnings from fontinst like this:

```
This character already appeared in a LIGTABLE LABEL (line 4312).
   (LABEL D 99 
              ) (COMMENT c)
```

Indeed, if I check the .vpl files output, I find duplicate entries. However, the later entry contains all the same information as the earlier one, plus my modifications, and the output seems to work OK.

What I'd like to know is, am I doing this the right way, and can I ignore the warnings?

Comment: Have a look at `multislot.sty` (part of `fontinst`).

Comment: Thanks. As far as I can tell, none of the possible `multislot` commands do what I want, as I want to have multiple \setslot...\endslot commands take effect (not just the first) and in the example quoted about changing l to lambda, the "buggy" behavior mentioned is exactly what I want to occur, i.e. retain the original kerns and ligatures. So maybe what I'm doing is right?

Comment: For example, in the above, I want to add a ligature for c and for s, while retaining all the existing ligatures and kerns.

Comment: Hm, I was especially worried about the double entries for slots 141 and 173, and about the "strange results" that according to `multislot.sty` might ensue, but if `vptovf` does the right thing (for you) by selecting the last entry, then maybe you should indeed just ignore the warning. Or else, could you also provide the driver file for further testing? (my `fontinst` skills have somewhat withered ...)

Comment: Ah yes, of course I want to reset those slots, that is, 141 and 173, but without getting the "first entry only" behavior of `\setslot` that `multislot.sty` gives.

Comment: Reading more carefully, it seems that `multislot.sty`'s `\resetslot` doesn't actually work (it retains kerns and ligatures), which means it's not going to help me. So maybe I do have to revert to a modified t1.etx.

Comment: (Note: as I said before twice, and hence perhaps unclearly, sorry, the entries I am getting are not the last entry, but the combination of all entries; in my case, for "c" for example, the original ligatures and kerns for "c" plus my additional ligature.)

Comment: So far, I can find no way to do this. I have resorted instead to shipping patches to existing `.etx` files.

Comment: What I would do is to copy `t1.etx` and rename it. Then change the name of the encoding and make the relevant modifications. This makes it safe to use alongside the standard version and ensures that you'll get a variant `.enc` file. (You don't want to end up with `t1.enc` because that should correspond to unmodified `t1.etx`.) Do the characters normally found in slots 141 and 173 exist in the font? If so, I would use `fontinst` to install a family based on the standard T1 and a family based on your modified version. At least, this is what I normally do myself.

Comment: @cfr, indeed I changed the name. Copying the file means I don't get any future changes, hence my preference for patching.

Comment: @ReubenThomas I think that's what you should want in this kind of case! In any case, you need to end up with a distinct `.enc` file regardless, so you'd want to patch the name of the encoding and the file name, right?

Answer (score 1):

Since I am making encodings that are mostly like the original, I want to get any updates to the original. I do patch the name of the encoding and change the file name; it would be easier if I could just import the original and override some of its settings, as then I could simply write the new file rather than having to patch the old.